# Quotient of $\mathbb P^n$ by the symmetric group $S_{n+1}$

Tags: finite-groups, projective-geometry

The projective space ${\mathbb P}^n$ of dimension $n$ over a field (let's take $\mathbb C$ for simplicity) can be viewed as the space of homogeneous coordinates $[x_0:\cdots :x_n]$ in the $n+1$ variables $x_0,\cdots,x_n \in \mathbb C$.

Can we describe, in simple terms, the geometry of the quotient space ${\mathbb P}^n/S_{n+1}$ where we consider the natural action of the symmetric group on $n+1$ elements, $S_{n+1}$, by permutation of all coordinates? Is this a toric variety?

It would be interesting to have a simple geometric description of the quotient space; for example, can we get a simple statement like the isomorphism between ${\mathbb P}^2$ and the quotient of ${\mathbb P}^1 \times {\mathbb P}^1$ by $S_2$ by switching the factors (the second symmetric power of ${\mathbb P}^1$)?

[The quotient ${\mathbb P}^1/S_2$ seems to be ${\mathbb P}^1$ again, but I do not see this clearly, nor how to proceed for higher dimensions]

Comment: The quotient is a weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,2,\dots,n+1)$.

Comment: @KevinCasto The slight issue with your argument is that after using the Newton's theorem now the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$ is not simply multiplication. It acts with different weights on the different variables of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: To make @JasonStarr's comment perhaps a little more pedagogical, consider the elementary symmetric functions $e_1,\ldots,e_{n+1}$ on $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ with the grading by their total degree in the latter variables: they are the homogeneous coordinates on the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,2,\ldots,n+1)$ seen as the geometric quotient.